# How to test jenkins

Tags: jenkins

We are maintaining a huge Jenkins instance with multiple plugins and jobs. Is there any test suite / automation test script available to test the Jenkins server - to validate if all the plugins are working fine, all server configurations are intact

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking after 9 masters in DEV, 9 in TEST and 9 in PROD.  One of the instances in PROD has 50+ permanent slaves connected to it.

The client is also making use of the swarm-slave plugin meaning there are a number of temporary slaves spinning up and down.

Hundreds if not thousands of jobs.

The approach we are taking to manage the stability of the PRODUCTION service being offered to other internal "end-users" is to add more rigour by making the DEV and TEST environment Internal-Use-Only to our team so that we have a test bed for core and plugin updates so we can determine impacts and plan for them when we eventually make the upgrades in Production.